# Nvd3 - scatter chart won't load despite adding all external resources

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, charts, nvd3.js

Please have a look at [this JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/38wufygo/). I'm trying to follow [a tutorial](http://lsxliron.github.io/nvd3Tutorial/) to create a very basic scatter chart in NVD3.js, but to no avail.

```
 function createBasicChart1(){

    var chart;

    nv.addGraph(function(){
        //Create chart
        chart = nv.models.scatterChart()
                .showLegend(false)                     // Remove legend (will put it back later)
                .showDistX(true)                       // Show X axis
                .showDistY(true)                       // Show Y axis
                .useVoronoi(false)                     // For now, disable hovering on points
                .color(d3.scale.category10().range())  // Colormap
                .duration(500);                        // Fade in duration


        // Generate toy data
        data = [{key: "", values:[{x:0,y:0},{x:1,y:1}, {x:3, y:3}, {x:3, y:10}]}];

        //Add chart to page
        d3.select("#basicChart1").datum(data).call(chart)

        // Register chart with  window resize event
        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

        return chart
    });
}
```

Could you please tell what I'm missing here? I've added all the resources like the tutorial says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one mistake from you and one mistake from the tutorial's author.

Your mistake is that the ID of the SVG is `basicChart1`, not `basicChart`. Actually, it is on the tutorial:

> When you write the javascript code, make sure to change the d3 selector id to a one that will match with the template.

The author's mistake is a little bit more strange: in his tutorial, the author never calls `createBasicChart1`. But, of course, unless it is an IIFE, you have to call it:

```
createBasicChart1()
```

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5eydu463/